# gcc manual not found

Tags: gcc

I wanted to see gcc's maual but

```
$ man gcc
No manual entry for gcc
See 'man 7 undocumented' for help when manual pages are not available.
$ man gcc-XX
No manual entry for gcc-XX
$sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ stretch main contrib non-free rpi
deb-src http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ stretch main contrib non-free$
#deb http://apt.adafruit.com/raspbian/ stretch main
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get --reinstall install man gcc
$ man gcc
#same as above
```

Where's the problem?
Should i change sources.list.d/raspi.list?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The documentation for GCC is actually contained in its own package<sup>1</sup>, [gcc-doc](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/gcc-doc).

Just run:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-doc
```

and then `man gcc` will work as expected.

Note that your attempt, `sudo apt-get --reinstall install man gcc` asks `apt-get` to try and install two packages, `man` and `gcc`. `man` doesn't exist as a package in the repositories, and `gcc` will just be reinstalled as you've asked, but it won't find the manual for GCC doing that. You cannot use `apt-get` in that way, unfortunately.

---

<sup>1 `gcc-doc` is actually a [metapackage](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MetaPackages) which just depends on the relevant version of the docs (e.g. `gcc-6-doc` for Stretch, `gcc-4.9-doc` for Jessie, etc). This means that you should get the right version of the docs by default, although you can also verify that the version is correct as described by joan below.</sup>

Comment: You probably need to get a package against the gcc version, e.g. gcc-6-doc if `gcc -v` reports you are using version 6.

Comment: sorry if i'm bad, it's my first question here. Sorry!

Comment: i installed gcc-6-doc and run man gcc and it worked!

Comment: Rather random, somewhat sketchy Raspbian (Debian 10.2.0 Buster released 2019 November 16 Saturday) has gcc version 8.3.0 (Raspbian 8.3.0-6+rpi1) yet "no installation candidate" for gcc-doc and gcc-8-doc but apt-get install 'gcc*doc' reveals that `apt-get install gcc-7-doc' works.